# c# Regular Expression for Number Range Decimal

Tags: regex, range

I'm trying to build up some regular expressions to validate some textbox controls. I have done some research and testing but cannot get this one working. Examples of what i am trying to create regular expressions for are as follows:

Range 0-10 digits, and 0 or 2 decimal places

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(0|([1-9][0-9]{0,9}))(\.[0-9]{1,2})?` is what you want.

Of course you can use `\d` for `[0-9]` instead. I used `[0-9]` to aid in understanding

Comment: this solution, no matches only digits, like 1, or 2, that´s its my problem

Comment: "(^(?:\\d|[0-9])$)|(^[0-9]([\\.\\,][0-9]{1,3})?$)";

Comment: Used http://www.nvcc.edu/home/drodgers/ceu/resources/test_regexp.asp to test, seems to work. I admit I forgot the final ?.